# jQuery function into ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery for a while but it is the first time I need to create my own function. (I'm using noConflict)

I have a code who work like this :

```
jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery("#tabs-3").dynatree({
            checkbox: true,
            onActivate: function(dtnode) {
                alert("You activated " + dtnode);
            }
        });

        //etendre tt les noeuds
        jQuery("#tabs-3").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(dtnode){
                dtnode.expand(true);
            });
    });
```

The code above is working, BUT, this part of code is in an ajax call, it worked for the first time when I called it, but not the second time or in future. when i call it with a function it gives error "jQuery.mytree is not a function". So what's wrong in my code. please help me .

```
(function(jQuery){
        jQuery.fn.extend({
            mytree: function (mytreename) 
            {
            alert(mytreename);
                jQuery(mytreename).dynatree({
                    checkbox: true,
                    onActivate: function(dtnode) {
                        alert("You activated " + dtnode);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        jQuery.mytree('#tabs-3');
    })(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual error?

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you do jQuery.fn.extend, it extends your selector.

For example:

```html
<div id = "tabs-3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(jQuery){
        jQuery.fn.extend({
            mytree: function mytree() {
                console.log("My tree ", this.attr("id"));
                // Do your cool AJAX calls 
            }
        });
        jQuery("#tabs-3").mytree();
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Will work. Inside mytree(), this is the result of your selector.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, the function seems good, I get the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to call like,

```
jQuery("#tabs-3").mytree();
```

Answer (score 0):

Arf I run into the next problem due to my construction I believe. The function is in a php lets call it 1.php.

1.php call in ajax 2.php

2.php contain a code who create a structure in

... (this part works).
In 2.php I call mytree, I don't get any error and the log works. But the dynatree doesn't work.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
            mytree: function mytree() {
                console.log("My tree ", this.attr("id"));
                jQuery(this.attr("id")).dynatree({
                    checkbox: true,
                    onActivate: function(dtnode) {
                        alert("You activated " + dtnode);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Anything to do for it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To call dynatree,

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
        mytree: function mytree() {
            console.log("My tree ", this.attr("id"));
            jQuery("#"+this.attr("id")).dynatree({
                checkbox: true,
                onActivate: function(dtnode) {
                    alert("You activated " + dtnode);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaaaaaaaand I missed the "#" ;)

Ok, now It works like earlier, the first time I call the ajax everything is all right.

But when I click back on the link who call the ajax I get the ul li part not on dunatree. I have the log so it pass in the function. I can't figure why it doesn't make ul li in dynatreee. :(

Comment: I suggest opening another question for that, and put dynatreee in tags.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer here!

I call now the function on the success call ajax on 1.php. (I think it's best coding just for that)

But before i check may tabs content, if it's not empty (previous tree) i destroy it before recreate it.

```
success : function(msg) 
                                    {
                                        if(msg!="")
                                        {
                                            //jQuery("#tabs-3").html(msg);
                                            (function(jQuery){
                                                //alert('Pass!'+jQuery("#tabs-3").text());
                                                if(jQuery("#tabs-3").text()!="")
                                                {
                                                    jQuery("#tabs-3").dynatree("destroy");
                                                }
                                                jQuery("#tabs-3").html(msg);
                                                jQuery("#tabs-3").mytree();
                                            })(jQuery);
                                        }
                                    }
```

Maybe not the more efficient but the best i found ;)

Special thanks to arun kumar!